# Rails email previews when not using mail method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailgun

I am using Mailgun's Ruby API to send emails from standard Rails mailers. However, since I'm not using the `mail` method, previews don't work:

`You are trying to preview an email that does not have any content. This is probably because the mail method has not been called`

Is there a way to preview mailers when not using the `mail` method? Preferably, one that doesn't require a gem.

Here's a sample of a mailer:

```
class SuppliersMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_user_details supplier
    @supplier = supplier

    message = Mailgun::MessageBuilder.new
    message.from default_params[:from]
    message.add_recipient :to, "email@example.com", {'first' => "Anna"}
    message.subject "My subject"
    message.set_html_body template_to_html_string("path/to/template")
    message.test_mode(true) if Rails.env.test?

    client.send_message ENV["MAILGUN_DOMAIN"], message
  end

  private

  def client
    Mailgun::Client.new ENV['MAILGUN_KEY']
  end
end
```

And the previewer class:

```
class SuppliersMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_user_details
    SuppliersMailer.send_user_details supplier
  end

  private

  def supplier
    Supplier.last
  end
end
```